# C# Progressbar in new Form

Tags: c#, progress-bar

Good day everybody,

I am currently trying to integrate a progress bar into my program.

My Idee:

A new form should open with the progress bar, which should remain open until the method is finished.

```
public void addatengenerieren()
    {
        // Login Name generieren
        if (textBox_zweitname == null || textBox_zweitname.Text == "") // Wenn leer dann
        {
            textBox_login_name.Text = textBox_vorname.Text.Substring(0, 1) + textBox_nachname.Text;
            textBox_anzeige_name.Text = textBox_nachname.Text + ", " + textBox_vorname.Text;
        }
        else
```

However, I always get the following error message:

`System.InvalidOperationException: "Ungültiger threadübergreifender Vorgang: Der Zugriff auf das Steuerelement textBox_login_name erfolgte von einem anderen Thread als dem Thread, für den es erstellt wurde."`

Calling up the progress bar looks like this:

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (Progressbar pb = new Progressbar(addatengenerieren))
        {
            pb.ShowDialog(this);
        }
    }
```

My progressbar form says the following:

```
public partial class Progressbar : Form
{
    public Action Worker { get; set; }
    public Progressbar(Action worker)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        if (worker == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        Worker = worker;
    }
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker).ContinueWith(t => { this.Close(); }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I think it's because the progressbar form spawns a new thread and thus can't access the main form's controls

Can someone help me ? I'm new to two forms that should communicate with each other :).

Comment: I would assume `textBox_vorname` is just empty and calling Substring on it just simply fails.

Comment: Yes you was right, sorry wrong error message postet. Now corrected in the post.

Comment: You can use a background worker class to handle updating the UI.

Comment: I assume you don't start the task to update only the UI you do something different then that. If possible separate the UI updating part from the part that actually should be processed in the background. Then do the UI updating part after the task is done.

Comment: Okay but on whitch code line I need to use the background worker ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I did everything that has to do with the UI via invoke, so I was able to solve the problem with the wrong thread and now it works without problems.

```
Invoke(new Action(() => UI-Code }));
```